# Image from Firebase not showing up in TableView Cell [Swift]

Tags: swift, image, uitableview, firebase

I'm attempting to display an image from my Firebase database in a TableView cell, however, when I run my app, the cell shows up blank. Everything seems to be connected to the storyboard, and Firebase is connected (in the database, the reference to the image is labeled as 'imageURL'), so I'm assuming it's a problem within the code itself. The code is shown below:

**Post.swift**

```
import Foundation
import Firebase
import FirebaseStorage
import FirebaseDatabase

class Post {
    private var _image: String!
    private var _imageKey: String!
    private var _imageRef: FIRDatabaseReference!

    var postImg: String {
      get {
         return _image
      } set {
        _image = newValue
      }
    }

    var imageKey: String {
        return _imageKey
    }


    init(imgUrl: String) {
        _image = imgUrl
    }

    init(imageKey: String, imageData: Dictionary<String, AnyObject>) {
        _imageKey = imageKey

        if let postImage = imageData["imageUrl"] as? String {
            _image = postImage
         }
        _imageRef = 
        FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("images").child(_imageKey)
    }

}
```

**PostCell.swift**

```
import UIKit
import Firebase
import FirebaseDatabase

    class PostCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var postImg: UIImageView!

    var searchedPost: Post!
    var searchedPostKey: FIRDatabaseReference!

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        // Initialization code
    }

    override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

        // Configure the view for the selected state
    }

    func configCell(searchedPost: Post, img: UIImage? = nil) {
        self.searchedPost = searchedPost

        if img != nil {
            self.postImg.image = img
        } else {

            let ref = FIRStorage.storage().reference(forURL:  searchedPost.postImg)
            ref.data(withMaxSize: 10 * 1000, completion: { (data, error) in

                if error != nil {
                    print(error) 
                } else {  
                    if let imgData = data {                         
                        if let img = UIImage(data: imgData){ 
                            self.postImg.image = img
                        }
                    }
                }
            })
        }

    }

}
```

**ViewController.swift**

```
import UIKit
import Firebase
import FirebaseDatabase

    class LeftView: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

    var images = [Post]()
    var searchedPost: Post!
    var imagePicker: UIImagePickerController!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        tableView.delegate = self
        tableView.dataSource = self
        imagePicker = UIImagePickerController()
        imagePicker.allowsEditing = true
        imagePicker.delegate = self

        FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("images").observe(.value, with:
        {(snapshot) in
            if let snapshot = snapshot.children.allObjects as? [FIRDataSnapshot] {

                self.images.removeAll()

                for data in snapshot {
                     print(data)
                    if let imageDict = data.value as? Dictionary<String, AnyObject> {
                        let key = data.key
                        let searchedPost = Post(imageKey: key, imageData: imageDict)
                        self.images.append(searchedPost) 
                    }
                }
            }
                self.tableView.reloadData()
        })
    }

    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return images.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let searchedPost = images[indexPath.row]
        if let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "PostCell") as? PostCell {
            cell.configCell(searchedPost: searchedPost)
            return cell
        } else {
            return PostCell()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: There are 2 scenarios why your cell gets blank:
1) You're calling tableView.reloadData() too soon, when there is no image yet, or you're making an error when getting the snapshot from Firebase. Put some prints inside for loops, inside if statements and see which one gets called, and which don't and investigate.
2) You return an empty PostCell() because you didn't specify the reusableCell "PostCell".

Answer (score 1):

You need to reload tableview after you get images from firebase.
Add This line

```
self.tableView.reloadData()
```

After

```
self.images.append(searchedPost)
```

Also You need to set your image in Main Queue. Use This in Configure Cell method

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
      self.postImg.image = img
}
```

Instead of

```
self.postImg.image = img
```